# Which Venture Capital firms are especially interested in Bitcoin?

Tags: investing

1. Which have invested into Bitcoin or Bitcoin companies?
2. Which have shown "more interest than average" (e.g. Pamir from [Hummingbird Ventures](http://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?company=Hummingbird%20Ventures&trk=prof-0-ovw-curr_pos) organized the [Bitcoin London Conference](http://btclondon.com/))?

Comment: See also https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=267727.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There hasn't been a definitive survey of the venture Capital industry but [Boost VC](http://boost.vc) has made several bitcoin investments. Its founders Adam Draper and Brayton Williams are responsible for organizing the [Boost Bitcoin Fund](http://onbitcoin.com/2013/05/25/boost-bitcoin-fund/) which several venture capital firms are participating in. There are also currently 7 bitcoin companies in their 2013 class of startups.

Answer (score 1):

From [AKCoins's answer](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=267727.msg2863623#msg2863623):

Coinbase has raised $6 million from all the big VCs:

- Start Fund
- Y Combinator
- Ribbit Capital
- Union Square Ventures
- Garry Tan
- SV Angel
- Greg Kidd
- FundersClub
- Adam Draper
- IDG Ventures